solr admin ui not loading
enter image description here
Although the Solr service is running, I am unable to access the Admin UI. We confirmed that Solr is active and listening on port 8983, but attempts to reach the Admin interface were unsuccessful. Firewall settings were checked to ensure that port 8983 is open, and the solr.in.sh configuration was reviewed to confirm that SOLR_ADMIN_UI_DISABLED is set to false, which should allow the Admin UI. Despite these configurations, accessing the Admin UI still fails
I installed and started the Solr service, and it appears to be running correctly. I expected to access the Solr Admin UI through the browser by navigating to http://localhost:8983/solr, but I was unable to reach the interface. I checked the solr.in.sh file to ensure that SOLR_ADMIN_UI_DISABLED is set to false and confirmed that Solr is listening on port 8983. Despite these checks and ensuring the firewall allows access to this port, I still cannot access the Admin UI.

why do you need SOLR admin UI with CKAN ?
